# using Guava's Resources.readLines to read from an HTTP service

Tags: java, http, url, guava

I want to `readLines` from a URL, which resolves to an HTTP service. I can use

```
Resources.readLines(url, Charsets.SOMETHING)
```

from `com.google.common.io`.

This works, but the class javadoc for Resources states the following, without further explanation:

> Note that even though these methods use URL parameters, they are usually not appropriate for HTTP or other non-classpath resources.

Why is this method inappropriate for reading from an HTTP service, and what is the recommended approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `URL` to send an HTTP request, the typical process is

```
URL url = new URL(someStringUrl);
HttpUrlConnection con = (HttpUrlConnection) url.openConnection();
// do some stuff with con, add headers, add request body, etc.
con.getInputStream(); // get body of response
```

The `URL` given to `Resources` skips all that. The methods in `Resources` depend on `URL#openStream()` which skips any modifications to the `URLConnection`, ie. is equivalent the `url.openConnection().getInputStream()`. It's possible you'll get any number of 400 level error codes from the HTTP response because your request wasn't correct.

This won't happen with class path resources because the protocol is simple. You just copy the bytes.

Comment: Good point. I'd actually only tried for GET requests on a simple service requiring no headers. So I suppose a `CharSource` wrapping a `ByteSource` creating and preparing the connection then returning `connection.getInputStream()` is the way to go. (Wrapping here allows you to pick a CharSet.)

Comment: @JoeKearney For HTTP requests, I'd really recommend you use a full blown Http Client.

Comment: @JoeKearney: Yeah, if you want to read from an HTTP URL and you'd like to be able to use Guava's I/O utilities for it, a `ByteSource` that opens a connection, sets it up as needed, and then connects and returns the input stream in the `openStream()` method is probably the way to go.

Comment: @ColinD While we have you here, does Google have a publicly available HTTP client?